# How to find the mean of a column in R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, mean

Here is my csv file I'm using.

```
my.xldataset <- read.csv('http://www.math.smith.edu/sasr/datasets/help.csv')
```

Here's my attempt at finding the mean of column "mcs1".

```
mean(my.xldataset$mcs1)
```

All I'm getting in return is an "NA". Where exactly am I going wrong here? Thank you

Comment: As @akrun said, you have `NA` values in your data frame so you need to use `na.rm=TRUE`

Comment: `help(mean)` would have also led you to the answer.

Comment: Why did you mark it duplicate. Its a different question.... @RichScriven

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that there are `NA` values in the column, so use `na.rm=TRUE`

```
mean(my.xldataset$mcs1, na.rm=TRUE)
```

or it could be that the column is not `numeric`.  In that case, check the

```
str(my.xldataset)
```

or

```
class(my.xldataset$mcs1)
```

---

By checking the dataset,

```
any(is.na(my.xldataset$mcs1))
#[1] TRUE
```

the `NA` elements are indeed in the dataset.  So, use the `na.rm=TRUE`.

Answer (score 3):

As @akrun noted, it is probably because of `NA` in that column of data.
You can also run:

```
summary(my.xldataset$mcs1)
```

which will report min, max, median, quartiles etc... as well as give you the number of NA's :)

```
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
  6.677  30.210  42.440  40.980  52.730  69.940     207
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? The mean is listed in the output from summary().  The output is posted above. Not only does it provide the mean, but it does so with NA's, and reports the number of NAs.  How does this not answer the OP's question?

Comment: You are right. `summary` does include the mean. I removed my down vote.